# Can I set a custom attribute on an android layout include tag?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to set a custom attribute on an include tag for a layout whose root is a custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:archxs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.archxs.bincalc"
    android:id="@+id/calculatorRowMenuAnchor" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <include android:id="@+id/calculatorrowmenu_result_running"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             archxs:isRunningResult="true"
             layout="@layout/single_line_result" />
...
```

includes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.archxs.bincalc.SmallIntegerResultView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true">
...
</com.archxs.bincalc.SmallIntegerResultView>
```

but the custom attribute is not set:

```
public SmallIntegerResultView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    final TypedArray styled = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ResultView);
    try {
        m_isRunningResult = styled.getBoolean(R.styleable.ResultView_isRunningResult, false);
    } finally {
        styled.recycle();
    }
}
```

Should this work? If not why? If yes what am I doing wrong?

Thanks all?

Comment: Instead of giving height width to layout in include give to the parent in that layout(single_line_result)

Comment: I have the same doubt. Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is maybe a little late but as I had a similar problem :

did you declare your custom attribute in attrs.xml ?

Look at this link for more explanations : [custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets](http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/)

Comment: Your link is dead (404)

Comment: sorry it's been a long time since and I totally forgot how I managed that
I guess the way to do it changed too by the way